# Bash run command according to environment variable

Tags: bash, environment-variables

See I wanna copy a file to a destination: `cp filename /home/example/temp.txt`.

The question the `filename` will be changed by some programes, and the new name of  it will be written in file `/home/example/.env`.

What I want is alias something like `alias cpf=cp ${filename} /home/nope/temp.txt` to .bashrc, then what I need is only run `cpf` if I want to copy the latest `finename` to `/home/example/temp.txt`.

---

What I have tried:

`eval $(grep -v "^#" "/home/example/.env") cp ${filename} /home/nope/temp.txt`

and faild to get `${filename}`.

Is there some changes to make what I tried work?

Comment: `the new name of it will be written in file /home/example/.env` In what format? `And I don't what to write a function which will first source /home/example/.env to expose all variables.` What about writing a function that will first source the file without "exposing" the variables?

Comment: "And I don't what to write a function which will first source" - I'm curious as to why not? It will affect *only* the environment of the script you're running, which will soon disappear. And it will allow you to handle more complex setups like `prefix=xyzzy; suffix=plugh; filename=${prefix}_${suffix}`. "Let the shell do what the shell is best at" would be my advice.

Comment: @paxdiablo Yeah, you're right! And I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example `.env`:

```
key1='do not put me in the environment'
key2=1231
filename=thisvaluechanges
key4="I hate being evaluated"
```

You only want to evaluate the line with `filename`. First test how you can select that line, something like

```
grep "^filename=" /home/example/.env
# or
sed -n 's/^\s*filename\s*=\s*/filename=/p' /home/example/.env
```

Next you can `source` the selected line.

```
source <(grep "^filename=" /home/example/.env)
```

When the filename is a fixed string (without `$()` that needs to be evaluated), you can do without `source`:

```
cp $(grep "^filename=" /home/example/.env) /home/nope/temp.txt
```

Before putting this in an `alias`, remember that a `function` can do everything an `alias` can, and can do more. You "should" stop using `alias`.
When you have three or four files like filename1, 2, 3, 4, you can use a function with an argument:

```
cpf() {
   if (( $# = 0 )); then
      echo "Usage: cpf filenumber"
   else
      cp $(grep "^filename${1}=" /home/example/.env) /home/nope/temp.txt
   fi
}
```

You can call the function with `cpf 2` for `filename2`.
When you want to put the filename in the environment, you can change the function

```
source <(grep "^filename${1}=" /home/example/.env)
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that assuming `/home/example/.env` contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
# bash sourcable file
filename=$(echo 123)
```

then you want:

```
#!/bin/bash
cpf() {
   (
      . /home/example/.env
      cp "$filename" /home/nope/temp.txt
   )
}
```

Notes:

- `eval` is evil. Your use of `eval $(grep...)` is very dangerous.
- Always remember to qoute your expansions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and suggestion! And I have three or four files like `filename1, 2, 3, 4`. And maybe sometimes I only want to copy one of them. Then I have to write 4 function `cpf1, 2, 3, 4`. Yeah, your answer will work, but just wanna know if there a way to make it just based on my current alias?